# Something like a suggested value for an empty cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I am tracking the work I do in an Excel workbook, which then I use in my weekly report at my company I work with. For this, I have a “begin” and “end” columns indicating when did I started to work.
I'm collecting these in Excel tables, put a formula in the “end” column in the template to show the expected end of day when my work day is over considering when did I started, and overriding a cell's value with the actual time I've done for the day, and using a conditional formatting, to highlight that indicating whether this value isn't filled in, but the formula is still occupying it. (I hope this was a meaningful sentence.) This was suitable for my purpose for quite a while until [card view feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-cards-view-to-work-with-table-data-on-your-phone-fda6099e-2de8-4a52-a926-90a7ee61a32b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us&fromar=1) arrived to Excel mobile.

In Excel mobile card view, if a row contains a formula, it cannot be edited. But I want to be able to edit the cells in the end column, while also know when is my end of day. Obviously I cannot use VBA macros, as it is not available for the mobile version; the macro-enabled files cannot even be opened in the mobile app. I could also introduce a new column, but that would further complicate my other formulas which are already fairly complicated as they are.

Is there a way to show a “suggestive” value to a cell that is newly introduced with a new row in to a table, either achieved by filling the cell in with that value, or showing a value that isn't in that cell; all this without using VBA macro?

At the moment, I've sent a feedback to Microsoft to allow removal of formulas from cells within card view, but I'm afraid, that my use-case is too specific for Microsoft to include, and I'm look for a possible alternative.

*I don't believe this question is quite suitable for stack-overflow, so I'm posting here, as I could not find a more suitable Stack Exchange site for this. Hope this is a proper place for this question.*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that rather than editing (and removing) a formula, simply separate them into different columns.

In this example, I would enter the start time in column B. Column C is calculated with:

```
=IF([@Start]<>"",B2+9/24,"")
```

i.e. I should expect to work at least 9 hours (inclusive of lunch).

I enter my actual end time in column D. I have conditionally formatted that column to be red if there is no value entered. This is to draw the eye to missing data.

Column E is simply D if it isn't empty, otherwise it's C.

```
=IF([@ActualEnd]<>"",[@ActualEnd],[@ExpectedEnd])
```

This is to allow a report to be produced on end times even if the actual end time was not entered.

Then column F is the number of hours between Start and ReportedEnd:

```
=IFERROR([@ReportedEnd]-[@Start],"")
```

[image]